# What is \3a in a CSS selector when copied from google?

Tags: css, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome dev tools to extract selectors from the page. 
When I have been copying selectors last time, I have stumbled upon an unusual one looking like this:

`body > div.h-full > div.bg-white.fixed.pin.pt-x11.md\3a pt-x14.overflow-y-auto > div > div.px-x4.pt-16.lg\3a p-0.lg\3a flex-1 > div.mb-x4 > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div.relative.group.mt-13.hidden.lg\3a block > button`

You can notice that there are few `\3a` inside those selectors. What do those mean?

Comment: It is "\3a", not "\3". Where "3a" represents the ASCII character (":") in hex - see https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes - "Theoretically, the : character can be escaped as \:, but IE < 8 doesn’t recognize that escape sequence correctly. A workaround is to use \3A instead."

Comment: @user2864740 updated. So what do those mean?

Comment: @user2864740 can you post this as an answer? I will mark it as correct

Comment: Sorry, but answering off-topic questions is not a good practice.

Comment: @Wais Kamal: How is this remotely off-topic lol. You've answered CSS questions before, so clearly you think those are on-topic. This one's no different.

Comment: Sorry but I meant to say duplicate. Very busy :)